# Movie on DD national related to Gandhi

Tags: identify-this-movie, documentary

I have seen a documentary/movie recently on DD national (Hindi-India) related to Gandhi. I couldn't see full movie and now I don't know its name. May be you can help.

The story goes like this. Rao (a government employee - I don't know the name of the actor)  gets selected to play Gandhi in a serial. Actress Jayanthi plays Kasturba Gandhi in that serial. Rao and his son (who is greedy) have some conflicts over money earned by Rao. Rao's son looses money in shares and goes to jail. The movie shows how Rao's life changes after he has started playing the role and earns a bit more than from his job. The movie is not in Hindi (Marathi or Kannada) and has subtitles in English when telecast (5th Oct 2014 night). From the vehicles in the background I can understand that it is a recent movie but it appears as a old film (camera work maybe).

Answer (score 4):

You are describing the 2010 movie [**Koormavatara**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koormavatara) which was broadcast on DD National at 10pm on October 5th as [this TV guide confirms](http://www.thehindu.com/features/metroplus/radio-and-tv/article6471433.ece).

The plot, from Wikipedia:

> The protagonist *[...]* is at the edge of retirement from government service, happens to play the role of Mahatma Gandhi in a television serial.